# phpからshellのexpectを実行したい

Tags: php

php

```
<?php    
exec('sh read.sh', $output);
print_r($output);
```

read.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh                       
 /usr/bin/expect -c "
 set timeout 10         
 spawn ssh test
 expect \"passphrase\" {
 send \"pass\r\"   
 expect \"Last login\"  
 send \"ls\r\"          
 expect \"$\"           
 send \"exit\r\"
 }                      
 interact               
 "
```

上記のコードのように
phpからexecでシェルを実行して、
sshで接続した先でlsをし、その結果をphpで受け取りたいです。

しかしコードの結果は

spawn ssh test

という、戻り値になってしまっています。
read.shを直接実行すると、意図したlsの結果が返却されます

sshの接続や、実行権限などは確認済みです。

なにか原因やコツなどわかるかたいましたらご教授ください。
宜しくお願いします。

環境
さくらVPS
php 5.5
apache2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP からシェルスクリプトを実行しますと tty(端末)が割り当てられません。そのため、interactive な操作ができなくなります。

```
spawn ssh -t test
```

としてみて下さい(`-t` オプションを追加)。これは ssh プロセスに強制的にpseudo tty(擬似端末)を割り当てます。